# How to plot multiple plots sharing both the x and y axis in a two by two format in R?

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I would like to plot my data in a two by two format. The four plots should have the same y and x axis. I would like to y and x axis label the outer axis as well. My issues have been in suppressing the x and y labels that come with the basic `plot()`in R. I use `yaxt="n"` and `xaxt="n"` but that doesn't workout.

```
x <- c(1, 4, 5, 5)  #fake data
y <- c(2, 4, 5, 4)  #fake data
data <- data.frame(x, y)  #fake data

plot_data1 <- function(data, ymax) {
    par(pty = "s")  # make the plot a square
    plot(data, type = "l", lwd = 2, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", ylim = c(0, ymax))
    my_at <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
    axis(side = 1, at = my_at, outer = TRUE)
    axis(side = 2, outer = TRUE)
}

plot_data2 <- function(data, ymax) {
    par(pty = "s")
    plot(data, type = "l", lwd = 2, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", ylim = c(0, ymax))
    my_at <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
    # axis(side=1, at= my_at, outer=TRUE) axis(side=2, outer=TRUE)        
}

plot_data3 <- function(data, ymax) {
    par(pty = "s")
    plot(data, type = "l", lwd = 2, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", ylim = c(0, ymax))
    my_at <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
    axis(side = 1, at = my_at, outer = TRUE)
    axis(side = 2, outer = TRUE)        
}

plot_data4 <- function(data, ymax) {
    par(pty = "s")
    plot(data, type = "l", lwd = 2, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", ylim = c(0, ymax))
    my_at <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
    axis(side = 1, at = my_at, outer = TRUE)
    # axis(side=2, outer=TRUE)
}

twobytwo <- function(data, ymax) {        
    nf <- layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE), respect = TRUE)  # for the two by two layout
    layout.show(nf)  # the two by two layout we want 
    nf
    plot_data1(data, ymax)
    plot_data2(data, ymax)
    plot_data3(data, ymax)
    plot_data4(data, ymax)
    title(xlab = "Age (years)", ylab = "Probability Density", outer = TRUE, line = 3)
}

twobytwo(data, ymax = 9)
```

The plots show up with the x and y labels even though I suppressed it using `yaxt="n". What do I tweak to get four neat plots in a two by two plot with the x axis and y axis showing?

Comment: you can suppress the x and y labels using `ylab=''` and `xlab=''` in the `plot()` function.

Comment: @bjoseph That does work! But the squares still don't touch...